# select rows based on time

Tags: sql-server

I have selected rows based on DateTime before using either:

```
DATEADD(day, -1, GetDate()) AND GETDATE()
```

to get the latest record since yesterday, and

```
 DECLARE @today DATETIME = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)  
DATEADD(mi, 00, DATEADD(hh, 8, @today)) AND DATEADD(hh, 9, @today)
```

In order to get a row that was between a certain time frame from the current day. Now I have a table that has a separate time and date column, so both of these do not work. I always get an error when I try either of the above methods saying:
"The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator." I know the problem is that I don't have a DateTime type column to reference. Is there a way to get a row between a certain time frame referencing separate time and date fields? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the Date and the Time fields together to create a single date/time field with which to compare:

```
create table #temp (id int, d date, t time)
insert into #temp values (1, '1/1/2000', '1:00 PM')
insert into #temp values (2, '1/1/2000', '2:00 PM')
insert into #temp values (3, '1/1/2000', '3:00 PM')

select * from #temp where cast(d as datetime) + cast(t as datetime) between '1/1/2000 1:10 PM' and '1/1/2000 2:30 PM'
```

So provided your `DATEADD()` is setup correctly, you could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE cast(DateField as datetime) + cast(TimeField as datetime) BETWEEN DATEADD(mi, 00, DATEADD(hh, 8, @today)) AND DATEADD(hh, 9, @today)
```

Comment: This doesn't really help; the OP said he has *separate* date and time columns, not a single `ADataField`. Also [`BETWEEN` is horribly wrong for date/time range queries](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Comment: @James, thanks for your response. As Aaron mentioned, what you suggested above does not work since I have separate time and date fields.

Comment: @Aaron, what other method(s) do you suggest to do date/time range queries?

Comment: Open-ended ranges (>= date1 and < date2). For date/time, BETWEEN is ambiguous and rarely what is really wanted.

Comment: Aaron and Rick -- sorry -- missed the 'separate field' part initially. You can combine the date and time fields by casting each as a datetime.  Then you can compare as though it was a single field.  I also agree that `between` is problematic.  I typically use Aaron's suggestion of (>= date1 and < date2).

Comment: Thanks James, your revised post helped alot. I will try to solve this problem using >=date1 and <date2 to see the difference myself. Again thanks to both for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @today DATE = SYSDATETIME();
DECLARE @start DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 8, @today);
DECLARE @end   DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @start);

SELECT ... FROM dbo.table ...
WHERE date_column = @today -- to narrow search first, efficiently, if indexed
AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, date_column), CONVERT(DATETIME, time_column)) >= @start
AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, date_column), CONVERT(DATETIME, time_column)) <  @end;
---- you may want <= here rather than <
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, this gave me a new way of approaching these kind of problems.